# PHP Compare two multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two multidimensional arrays like this:
Guest allow array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

and second one like this

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [property_id] => 6
            [guest_allow] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [property_id] => 9
            [guest_allow] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [property_id] => 62
            [guest_allow] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [property_id] => 72
            [guest_allow] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [property_id] => 76
            [guest_allow] => 4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [property_id] => 80
            [guest_allow] => 5
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [property_id] => 84
            [guest_allow] => 3
        )
)
```

So I have to match guest array all values are present in second array as well as I have to check guest values is less than to second array of `guest_allow`. If there is not match single value return empty array. If match value so return only match value. I want return array like this:

```
       Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [property_id] => 6
            [guest_allow] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [property_id] => 9
            [guest_allow] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [property_id] => 62
            [guest_allow] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [property_id] => 72
            [guest_allow] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [property_id] => 84
            [guest_allow] => 3
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [property_id] => 76
            [guest_allow] => 4
        )
)
```

Is it possible return this type array? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `$guestArr` is your guest array and `$secondArr` is your second array, the solution would be like this:

```
foreach($secondArr as $key => $arr){
    if(!in_array($arr['guest_allow'], $guestArr)){
        unset($secondArr[$key]);
    }
}

// display $secondArr array
var_dump($secondArr);
```

Here's the [**live demo**](https://eval.in/704305).

Comment: Can I compare greater than or equal to?

Comment: @dhanashri In what way you want to use *greater than or equal to* here?

Answer (score 0):

```
$first = [1, 2, 3];
$second = [
    ['property_id' => 6, 'guest_allow' => 2],
    ['property_id' => 66, 'guest_allow' => 3],
    ['property_id' => 76, 'guest_allow' => 4],
    ['property_id' => 86, 'guest_allow' => 2]
];

$result = array_filter($second, function($el) use ($first) {
    return in_array($el['guest_allow'], $first);
});
```